# How to Implement Application-based stickiness in ELB?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using sticky session using Duration based cookie generated by ELB, Now I want to use application based cookie in ELB. I created a cookie "STICKYSESSID" in laravel controller but how to send this cookie in each request? I am not aware about it. I am using multiple ajax call so Do i need to send this cookie in each ajax call also?

i dont have testing environment like ELB, instance to test. I have to implement this in live directly So I cant touch to live without enough knowledge.

Comment: I am aware about the changes from AWS side but not aware about application side changes ..  I am trying to give more clarity.. 
1.  Where should i create the cookie in application side so that it will be available for each request(I am using Laravel )? 
2. Do I need to send this cookie each time manually  ? I am not clear about the steps of application side changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via EC2 > Target groups > YourTargetGroup > Attributes > Edit as shown in the picture.
[image: AppBasedStickySession]

Comment: Can you pls tell the application side changes ?